# Escape Unicode Character 'POPCORN' to HTML Entity

Tags: java, apache-commons, html-escape-characters, unicode-escapes

I have a string with an emoji in it

```
I love
```

I need to escape that popcorn emoji with it's html entity so I get

```
I love &#x1f37f;
```

I'm am writing my code in Java and I have been trying different StringEscapeUtils libraries but haven't gotten it to work.  Please help me figure out what I can use to escape special characters like Popcorn.

For reference:

[Unicode Character Information](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f37f/index.htm)

[Unicode 8.0 (June 2015)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/version/8.0/index.htm)

Comment: If the receiving system expects an HTML document with a document encoding of US-ASCII, why not just serialize the entire document as such? Why focus on specific characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`CharSequence::codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) to get an `IntStream` of the code points and map them to strings, and then collect them, concatenating to a single string:

```
public String escape(final String s) {
    return s.codePoints()
        .mapToObj(codePoint -> codePoint > 127 ?
            "&#x" + Integer.toHexString(codePoint) + ";" :
             new String(Character.toChars(codePoint)))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

For the specified input, this produces:

```
I love &#x1f37f;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hacky, because I don't believe there is a ready made library to do this; assuming you can't simply use UTF-8 (or UTF-16) on your HTML page (which should be able to render  as is), you can use [`Character.codePointAt(CharSequence, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt-java.lang.CharSequence-int-) and [`Character.offsetByCodePoints(CharSequence, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#offsetByCodePoints-java.lang.CharSequence-int-int-)<sup>1</sup> to perform the conversion if the given character is outside the normal ASCII range. Something like,

```
String str = "I love ";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (ch > 127) {
        sb.append(String.format("&#x%x;", Character.codePointAt(str, i)));
        i += Character.offsetByCodePoints(str, i, 1) - 1;
    } else {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

which outputs (as requested)

```
I love &#x1f37f;
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>Edited based on [helpful comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532687/escape-unicode-character-popcorn-to-html-entity/57532784?noredirect=1#comment101531424_57532784) from Andreas.</sub>

Comment: I’m not actually rendering this on an html page.  I’m passing it to another system and my focus is on keeping the behavior the same as a legacy system.

Comment: You should encode anything above 127, not 255, so the result only consists of ASCII characters.

Comment: `Character.codePointCount(str, i, i + 1)` always returns `1`. I believe you meant `i = Character.offsetByCodePoints(str, i, 1) - 1;`, with the `-1` at the end needed to offset the `i++` in the `for` loop. --- To see the problem, insert e.g. `ň` in the string, and the character immediately following will be skipped.

Comment: I would prefer using `str.codePoints()` to get a stream and process the code points that way. Using `codePointCount` and `offsetByCodePoints` is too low-level, tedious, and easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the [emoji4j library](https://github.com/kcthota/emoji4j) works. It has a simple `htmlify` method for HTML encoding.

For example:

```
String text = "I love ";

EmojiUtils.htmlify(text); //returns "I love &#127871"

EmojiUtils.hexHtmlify(text); //returns "I love &#x1f37f"
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Given a string that contains an emoji plus other characters, this doesn't provide any way to escape that string.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks for pointing that out! I edited my answer so it uses the library's method for converting emojis to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `unbescape` library: [unbescape: powerful, fast and easy escape/unescape operations for Java](https://www.unbescape.org/index.html).

## Example

Add the dependency into the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unbescape</groupId>
    <artifactId>unbescape</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The usage:

```java
import org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscape;
import org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscapeLevel;
import org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscapeType;

<…>

final String inputString = "\uD83C\uDF7F";
final String escapedString = HtmlEscape.escapeHtml(
    inputString,
    HtmlEscapeType.HEXADECIMAL_REFERENCES,
    HtmlEscapeLevel.LEVEL_2_ALL_NON_ASCII_PLUS_MARKUP_SIGNIFICANT
);

// Here `escapedString` has the value: `&#x1f37f;`.
```

For your use case, probably, either `HtmlEscapeType.HTML4_NAMED_REFERENCES_DEFAULT_TO_HEXA` or `HtmlEscapeType.HTML5_NAMED_REFERENCES_DEFAULT_TO_HEXA` should be used instead of `HtmlEscapeType.HEXADECIMAL_REFERENCES`.